# How to export dependency licenses information to csv?

Tags: flutter

Having an application with about 30 dependencies, we report about the licenses in the app via the default [`showLicensePage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showLicensePage.html).

How can we export this list to a CSV format (including transitive dependencies)? I am looking for something like this:

```
package name,transitive (direct/transitive),license,link
some_package,direct,MIT,https://github.com/someone/some_package
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LicenseFinder](https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder) has [support for flutter](https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder/pull/875) since version 7.0.0 and supports many output formats including csv. The good thing over e.g. [flutter_oss_licenses](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_oss_licenses) is that it also provides the license name (not only the license text) and also has many other features (e.g. allowing a set of licenses, CI-support, other languages/package-managers support etc.), it is actively maintained by pivotal and is itself MIT licensed.

For example, one can use the docker version to run it (see [README](https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder) - for more information how to run the tool).

Then you can get a csv report for your flutter project with a command like this:

```
cd some_flutter_project
docker run -v $PWD:/scan -it licensefinder/license_finder:7.0.1 /bin/bash -lc "cd /scan && PUB_CACHE=~/.pub license_finder report --format=csv -p"
```

This command will mount the current working directory to the docker container and analyze it. The `-p` option runs `flutter pub get` in the docker container to setup the dependency cache that is then analyzed.

Note that the command will print the result to standard out, but you can, for example, pipe it to a file `(command from above) > out.csv`.

Comment: note that the LicenseFinder docker image has hardcoded flutter 2.8.1 so you might want to change it to your desired flutter version and build the image on your own. see https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder/blob/master/Dockerfile#L227